# Error in Excel with epplus (HYPERLINK) formula

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have a problem with `epplus` i.e. it generates an excel document with different types of data in one of the columns I have to put a link to some resource, I created a code that does it and puts it all into the formula, throwing it to Excel, but after generating Excel and opening it I get the Error:

```
We Found A Problem With Some Content In Excel
```

After opening it returns the error:

> Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part

I no longer have any idea about this error, some good advice on how to fix / improve it?

My code:

```
                    foreach (var item in url)
                    {

                        if (url.First() == item)
                            cli.Add(String.Format(@"=HYPERLINK(""{0}"",""{1}"")&"" """, item.address, item.name));
                        else
                        if (url.Last() == item)
                            cli.Add(String.Format(@"&HYPERLINK(""{0}"",""{1}"")", item.address, item.name));
                        else
                            cli.Add(String.Format(@"&HYPERLINK(""{0}"",""{1}"")&""  """, item.address, item.name));
                    }
                    ws.Cells[row, 6].Style.WrapText = true;
                    ws.Cells[row, 6].Formula = String.Join("", cli);
```

Comment: did you check the generated hyperlink in debug mode ?

Comment: @Akshay yes, it lokks like:

 =HYPERLINK("https://someapp.com","xxx yyyy")&" "

Comment: ok, i see that you are using HYPERLINK to just put some data in form of url so its clickable. Can you show the sample value of url variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created this and it works fine. I can click on the link and it opens just fine.. Try this, I hope this is what you are looking for. I have changed the string format ..

```
using (ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet1");
            excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet2");
            excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet3");

            var worksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets["Worksheet1"]; 

            string FileRootPath = "http://www.google.com";

            string url  = String.Format("HYPERLINK(\"{0}\",\"" + "{1}" + "\")", FileRootPath, "Test display");

            worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Formula = url; // "HYPERLINK(\"" + FileRootPath + "\",\"" + "TEST display" + "\")";

            FileInfo excelFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\ProjectWork\test.xlsx");
            excel.SaveAs(excelFile);
        }
```